# Linking 2 select lists that are on different pages in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have 2 php html forms, both consisting of 1 select list. In the first form, I have a select list that asks the user to select their State. According to the state selection on the first page, when the user clicks submit, the second selection list should show the postcodes for that state.

I am having difficulty in performing this task as they 2 select lists are on 2 different pages, i know how to use javascript if they are on the same but i am a bit stumped as they are on different pages. Im not sure how to link them together.

```
State* <select id="state" name="state"">
                         <option value="">Select</option>
                         <option value="OKC">OKC</option>
                         <option value="NYC">NYC</option>
                         <option value="CAL">CAL</option>

     </select><br />
```

So if the user selects OKC from first list on the first page, the second list on the second page should show only postcodes for OKC

Comment: you could use sessions

Comment: Is there any reason not to use AJAX? I.e To retrieve the items in the appropriate second list once the selection is made in the first list.

Comment: i have tried using sessions and a switch statement but cannot seem to figure out how to implement a select list in the php part. Since this is for an assignment, we arent supposed to use AJAX because we havnt been taught how to use it @kevinabelita

Comment: @roro - then in that case, examine either of the PHP objects `$_POST` or `$_GET` - depending on whether the form submits via the `post` or the `get` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you absolutely need to have 2 different PHP pages for your `select` elements, you could use an HTTP parameter. For example you could have the first form have a submit button which takes you to the second PHP page:

firstpage.php:

```
<form action="secondpage.php" method="get">
    <select id="state" name="state">
         <option value="">Select</option>
         <option value="OKC">OKC</option>
         <option value="NYC">NYC</option>
         <option value="CAL">CAL</option>

    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="Next page" />

</form>
```

The submit button would take your browser to the `secondpage.php` but according to your state selection, it would attach a parameter, for example `secondpage.php?state=OKC`.

On `secondpage.php` you could use the parameter to your advantage:

```
$state = $_GET['state'];
```

Use PHP statements to dynamically generate your `<select>` element:

```
 <?php

$state = $_GET['state'];

$postcodes = null;

if($state == "NYC")
{
    $postcodes = array("postcode1", "postcode2");
}

if($state == "OKC")
{
    $postcodes = array("postcode3", "postcode4");
}

?>


<form action="anotherpage.php" method="get">
    <select id="postcode" name="postcode">

        <?php

        foreach ($postcodes as $p) 
        {
            echo '<option value="'.$p.'">'.$p.'</option>';
        }

        ?>


    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="Next page" />

</form>
```

Of course there are more efficient ways to go about this, but this should give you an idea.